# How to develop pagination in AngularJS by passing parameters to an AJAX service?

Tags: html, angularjs, json, pagination

I need to get to know how to paginate a page with 10 records per page. I have been searching online but unable to find any resources which explain that. So a simple example would be great or a link to a tutorial.

Comment: What lang are u using? 
İf c# check "staticpagedlist" for paging working with angular.https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/StaticPagedList.cs

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('app').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.currentPage = 1;

  $scope.tracks = [];
  getData();


  function getData() {
    $http.get("yourlink" + $scope.currentPage)
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.totalItems = response.data.info.num_results
        angular.copy(response.data.tracks, $scope.tracks)


      });
  }

//get another portions of data on page changed
  $scope.pageChanged = function() {
    getData();
  };


});
```

Also lets have a look at this [link](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/08/31/server-side-pagination-in-angularjs/) and its [example](http://code.ciphertrick.com/demo/server-pagination/).

Comment: can you please add all the code

Comment: thank you for this suggestion.can you add all the resourse

Comment: You can visit the link provided above. You will get all the code.

Comment: thankyou for this information

Comment: @G.Naresh If this has answered your question, you should click the green checkmark next to the answer to accept it.  The checkmark will change color to green to indicate that it's the accepted answer.  Upvotes show additional appreciation for good answers.